# Is there any actual GMSPlace attributions text for testing?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

The GMSPlace defines the "attributions" property as: "The data provider attribution string for this place. These are provided as a NSAttributedString, which may contain hyperlinks to the website of each provider." I'm using this in my app, but haven't been able to test this since every place I've looked up does not have any attributions.

My question is: does anyone know of a place I can lookup which includes attributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try the code from the example in https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/attributions#attributions-place?

I have use the code and found a place have the attribution with PlaceID `ChIJV4k8_9UodTERU5KXbkYpSYs`. I think you can also try and find more from that code.

Comment: Yes, I've used their code, but hadn't found any attribution strings. The place ID that you've provided is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Actually you can find there are some place at the bottom if you apply the code in that size, and find the attributing strings with those PlaceID. You can try if you want to have more test. Please help to accept the answer or vote up if you find the answer is helpful. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation points yet, so I can't up-vote your answer. (And I don't see a way to accept it, either!) Thanks for your answer; I'll come back later to up-vote and accept once I'm able.